# AngleSharp Как подключить прокси?

Tags: c#, парсер, proxy, anglesharp

Похожий вопрос уже был но там немного другой код, а я немного разобрался в своем коде и боюсь его сломать.

```js
//тут наверное подгружаем прокси?
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:80", false),
                PreAuthenticate = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false
            };
            
            var requester = new DefaultHttpRequester();
            //прописываем юзер агент, и для не совсем понятно как это происходит, это метод или что? 
                requester.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0";
                //из вопроса с сайта нужно сделать вот так .WithRequesters(httpClientHandler), но я так сделать не могу, у меня ошибка.
                var config = Configuration.Default.With(requester).WithDefaultLoader();
                var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
```

В общем то вопрос в том как мне подключить прокси?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам на свой вопрос)
Нужно дополнительно установить пакет **AngleSharp.io** через NuGet и тогда станет доступен метод `.WithRequesters()`
Получается вот так вот:

```js
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, false),
                PreAuthenticate = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false
            };
            var requester = new DefaultHttpRequester();
            
                requester.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0";
                var config = Configuration.Default.With(requester).WithDefaultLoader().WithRequesters(httpClientHandler);
                var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
```